# php: file_get_contents not working into if-statement

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements, file-get-contents

I have this code:

```
//A
if(condition1)
   {
   //B
   if(condition2)
      {
      //C
      }
   }
```

and a file_get_contents($url). I want this file_get_contents to run in "//C", but I notice this: in A works properly, but the same instruction, if put in "//B" or "//C", doesn't work, and "condition1" and "condition2" are both verified (when putting other instrution in B or C they work). I also tried this try/catch statement but without success:

```
try {
$content = file_get_contents($url);

if ($content === false) {
    // THIS is always verified
}
} catch (Exception $e) {
// NEVER RUNS
}
```

What can I do?

Comment: please post the complete code

Comment: Ah i see try catch and false.

Comment: Errors in PHP built-in functions don't signal errors, so try/catch won't do anything.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri It's a very long code, however syntax and parenthesis are ok

Comment: @Barmar What are your doubt? Can I explain you more?

Comment: You can cut some part of code, I wanna understand why in part A works and in other not... is unclear what is your problem in this way

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri here it is. Is a part of a Telegram bot.
`<?
$content = file_get_contents("php://input");
$update = json_decode($content, true);
if(!$update)
{
  exit;
}

//...
$cbid = isset($update["callback_query"]["id"]) ? $update["callback_query"]["id"] : "";
//...  
if($cbData!="")
{
    if($cbData=="asfasf")
 {
 $url='...';
 try {
  $content = file_get_contents($url);
  if ($content === false) {
     //ALWAYS Verified
  }
  else
  {
   //never runs
  }
 } 
 catch (Exception $e)
 {
    //never runs
 }

 }
}
//...
echo json_encode($parameters);
?>`

Comment: **EDIT:** the first `$content` and the `$content` into the `try` are NOT the same! I wrongly named the two variables, excuse me.
Also changing the name it doesn't work.

Comment: @G.Ianni Put the code in the question, not a comment. Comments don't have formatting.

Answer (score 0):

It never goes into catch because there is no RUNTIME ERROR to report, function ran succesfully without a crash.

```
try {
$content = file_get_contents($url);

    if ($content === false) {
       AREA 1
    }else{
       AREA 2
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
   AREA 3
}
```

If file is read succesfully -> AREA2

If FOR ANY REASON file couldnt be read (permissions, file not found,  anything) -> AREA1

If a RUNTIME ERROR occurs during file_get_contents execution -> AREA 3

Comment: If this code is put into my "//C" or "//B" it goes to "AREA 1", if I put the code into "//A" the function runs.

Comment: if Always it is false, it means file cant be read. for debug purposes  use asci characters for file name, use get_pwd() to see what is your script's path.

Comment: The problem is that outside of the if-statement the file (that is a URL) CAN be read, but not inside the if-statement. I don't think that can be a problem related to my script's path (that is the same in both cases)

Comment: $content is equal to file in //A. 
$content is equal to false in //B is that it ?

Comment: If you refer to the answer to AlessandroMinoccheri's comment, the two files are not the same, I have wrongly named the variable, however also changing names it doesn't work

Comment: nvm. so what u say is i can read the file in //A i see the file content but if i put same variable in if condition it returns false. are u sure u read the file ? in area //A

Comment: Yes, in //A the file is read (it's a Telegram API request that is correctly executed), i don't think that's an API problem, because the execution is the same in each point of the code (it only depends by what is written on the URL, that normally works - also in //A)

Comment: If the file is read, its done, i agree its not a api error since fil_get is the same function. There has to be a string inside of that $content if there is a string it wont get into that if statement. In short your code is correct man. Thats why he wanted full code.

Comment: What do you mean for "if there is a string it wont get into that if statement"?

Comment: if file_get_content read the file $content is a string. it wont get in to if. in short YOUR CODE IS CORRECT

Comment: Excuse me for the insistence, but this means that file_get_contents doesn't work, in general, into if-statements?

Comment: @G.Ianni That's not true. `file_get_contents` works the same everywhere.